# Wrong variable getting updated

Tags: c#, race-condition

I have been struggling with something that I found out to be very weird. Obviously, C# behaves this way but I was wondering how to prevent it. My code is very long so I've made a small example of my dilemma:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<Person> m_Persons = new List<Person>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Person p1 = new Person();
            p1.Name = "Jack";
            p1.Money = 10;
            m_Persons.Add(p1);

            Bank ph = new Bank();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                ph.Insert(p1);
                Console.WriteLine(p1.Money);
            }
        }
    }

    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Money { get; set; }
    }

    class Bank
    {
        private List<Person> m_Customers = new List<Person>();
        public void Insert(Person p_Person)
        {
            int index = m_Customers.FindIndex(item => item.Name == p_Person.Name);
            if (index > -1)
                m_Customers.ElementAt(index).Money += p_Person.Money;
            else
                m_Customers.Add(p_Person);
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above, my printings say:

```
10
20
40
80
```

Those values is to me right, but they should be stored in the bankclass and not in the object that are used as a reference in `Insert()`. Why is the p1-object getting updated?!

Comment: How many times do you count `new Person()` appearing in your code? That's how many `Person` objects you're dealing with. So if something is changing some property of some `Person` object, it must, logically, be affecting that *one* instance of `Person`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The p1 object is getting updated becaused `Person` is a reference type. This means that when you pass the object to methods, it's actually a reference TO the object which is being passed i.e. The p1 object is the exact same instance as the `Person` you've added to the bank. Therefore, if you update the `Person` in the Bank (which you do when you call the `Insert` method) the p1 object is also updated.

If you want to prevent this behaviour, you would have to create a new `Person` object within your loop. If you set the new `Person` object's properties to the same values each time, the `Person` in the bank will be updated, but not the `Person` object in your loop.

Alternatively you could change the Insert method so that instead of

```
m_Customers.Add(p_Person);
```

you use

```
m_Customers.Add(new Person{ Name = p_Person.Name, Money = p_Person.Money });
```

Comment: Ok! Just the kind of answer I was looking for! Is there a way to just use an object property without updating the object itself?

Comment: @user3360860 - Have edited my answer to include a way to just use the properties.

Comment: Ty for your answer. I got many good answers but this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

`Person` is a class, i.e. reference type. When you are inserting person to `m_Customers` list, you are actually creating new *reference* to same person instance, and adding this *reference* to list (list hold *references* to person instances). So, your program have one instance of person and six references to this instance. It does not matter which reference you will use to update person's money - your single instance will be updated at the end.

[image]

I also suggest you to read MSDN article [Value and Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Guys, downvoting means *This answer is not useful*. Can you explain what is wrong with this answer?

Comment: Ok! Just the kind of answer I was looking for! Is there a way to just use an object property without updating the object itself?

Comment: @user3360860 how exactly you want to use object property? If property is a value type (like integer), then you can read property value (i.e. create copy of value) and work with it

Comment: I just want to use the objectproperty Money to know how much to add to the bank, but not to update the personobject itself. Its like, I almost want to use Money as a constant but be able to change it at will :P I hope it makes sense :P

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy What did you use to create this diagram? It looks lovely.

Comment: @user3360860 sorry, was AFK. Answer is simple - you should have different instances of person which will hold different data. I added image which shows how your objects currently related to each other. As you can see, you have four references in `m_Customers` list to same person

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are always looping the same person:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    ph.Insert(p1);
    Console.WriteLine(p1.Money);
}
```

The above code will insert `p1` 4 times.

Comment: Yeah, thats right. But that shouldn't update the p1-object, should it? I never assign anything else than the value of 10 to that object, but still it gets higher values EDIT: I sounded sarcastic but I wasn't :)

Comment: @user3360860 It will increase the p1.Money. p1 is only created once, then when you add it to the bank, you're really just adding a *reference* to the original p1 object, not creating an identical one and adding that.

Comment: ok, so how do I create an identical object to use with the value from p1?

Answer (score 1):

In your `Insert` method you verify if the person already exists in the lists m_Customers, if exists, you update the money.

In your `Form1` Class you need to create people of different names, if the name is the same, the money will be updated.

Try to create people inside `for` statement and diferent names like this:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Bank ph = new Bank();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.Name = "Jack" + i;
            p.Money = 10;
            m_Persons.Add(p);

            ph.Insert(p);
            Console.WriteLine(p.Money);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was wondering how to use the Money value in the insert-method, but still have the value 10 on the p1-object :)